# Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto failed to create a new table

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

In the Hibernate configuration file, I created a property

```
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>.
```

When I run the project I got an error like this

```
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table MADHU.DBTEST9_14_2013 (STUDENTIDPK number(22,0) not null unique, STUDENTDEPTNN varchar2(20 char) not null, STUDENTNAMENN varchar2(20 char) not null, primary key (STUDENTIDPK))

Sep 16, 2013 3:16:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ORA-02261: such unique or primary key already exists in the table .
```

This is the auto generated query by Hibernate.
I want to know why Hibernate generated such type of query and failed to excute it.

I opened sqlplus command prompt and changed the query to

```
MADHU.DBTEST9_14_2013 (STUDENTIDPK number(22,0), STUDENTDEPTNN varchar2(20 char) not null, STUDENTNAMENN varchar2(20 char) not null, primary key (STUDENTIDPK))
```

This query working perfectly.

I used annotation based mapping

```
    @Id
@Column(name = "STUDENTIDPK")
public BigDecimal getStudentidpk() {
    return this.studentidpk;
}


@Column(name = "STUDENTNAMENN", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getStudentnamenn() {
    return this.studentnamenn;
}


@Column(name = "STUDENTDEPTNN", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getStudentdeptnn() {
    return this.studentdeptnn;
}
```

Comment: It seems like providing both `unique` and `primary key` makes oracle complain. Can you try that in command prompt?

Comment: hibernate created that query. as you said providing both unique and primary key is the problem. then why hibernate created both in query.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't know any better (???). Can you provide your entity mapping?

Comment: I used annotation based mapping           @Id
 @Column(name = "STUDENTIDPK")
 public BigDecimal getStudentidpk() {
  return this.studentidpk;
 }

 
 @Column(name = "STUDENTNAMENN", nullable = false, length = 20)
 public String getStudentnamenn() {
  return this.studentnamenn;
 }

 
 @Column(name = "STUDENTDEPTNN", nullable = false, length = 20)
 public String getStudentdeptnn() {
  return this.studentdeptnn;
 }

Comment: You can edit your question with a link at the bottom left of the question box. Add your code there.